# Showing $(Tp)(x) = x^2p(x)$ is a linear map (transformation)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

Define a linear map function $T: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ where $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all polynomials with real-valued coefficients. Now let $T$ belong to the set of all possible linear maps from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ to itself, i.e.: $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}), \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$ whereby we define this to be,

$$(Tp)(x) = x^2p(x) \tag{1}$$

for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and where $p : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial function.

To show that (1) is a linear map we must show that it follows additivity and homogeneity. I'm not quite sure how to show that (1) homogeneous. Thanks for any help!

Note: the above can be found in Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* on page 39.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial in the domain, and $k\in \mathbb{R}$.  Then $$T(kp(x))=x^2(kp(x))=k(x^2p(x))=kT(p(x))$$

Intuitively, $T$ shifts all the standard basis elements two over.  $T(1)=x^2, T(x)=x^3, T(x^2)=x^4$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

let $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+ a_2x^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot+a_nx^n$

Now let $\lambda\in \mathbb R$ then $\lambda p(x)=\lambda a_0+(\lambda a_1)x+(\lambda a_2)x^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot+(\lambda a_n)x^n$

Then $T(\lambda p(x))=x^2\lambda a_0+(\lambda a_1)x^3+(\lambda a_2)x^4+\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot+(\lambda a_n)x^{n+2}=\lambda x^2(a_0+a_1x+ a_2x^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot+a_nx^n)=\lambda T(p(x))$